# How to add compare product button

Tags: bigcommerce

I am new in bigcommerce so please let me how can i add compare product option with feature product on home page.

I have already enabled the compare checkbox from backend

Answer (score 0):

The compare object is accessed via the product-listing component when viewing a category page, and home.html uses different components that would need to be modified or replaced so that the compare object is available. You can find more about the compare object on the [BigCommerce dev docs here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/other-objects-and-properties-overview#compare).